# Create a sample with at least one of each element in R

Tags: r, random

Is there a way to create a sample with size `n` of a vector with `x` elements that will have at least one occurrence of each `x` element given that `n >= length(x)`?

Example:

```
> n = 10                                         # size of the sample
> vector <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")                # 
> sample(vector, size = n, replace = TRUE)       # 
 [1] "b" "c" "b" "d" "b" "d" "c" "d" "c" "d"     # "a", by chance, don't get selected
```

I want to have each element ocurring at least one time, how is it possible? Should I use another function?

Outputs examples:

```
> "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d" 
> "c" "c" "a" "c" "d" "c" "c" "c" "b" "d" 
> "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a"
```

Comment: I'm not fully certain @akruns method will always work (seems so), but a possible alternative could be `c(sample(vector), sample(vector, size = n - length(vector), replace = TRUE))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg woudn't this force "abcd" to always appears on the start (but not necessarily in that order)?

Comment: It will force the unique values to appear at the start- certainly, but not always in that order as we shuffle them too (we have two `sample` calls here). You could also sample the order if you wish. Try this instead (it will handle the overall order too) `sample(c(vector, sample(vector, size = n - length(vector), replace = TRUE)))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg this seems to work perfectly, thank you!